# Give inputs to Java program, which is running using RunTime.exec() on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, runtime.exec

I have a java snippet in a file User.java

```
public class User{
  public static void main(String d[]){
    try{
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String name = br.readLine();
      System.out.println("Hello "+name);
    }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Next, I have written another java program which runs above program, and its main function content is below.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc1 = runtime.exec("javac MY_PATH/User.java");
Process proc2 = runtime.exec("java -cp MY_PATH User");
```

This code is working for all java snippets except which needs input. How should I give input for readLine(); methods.

Comment: I am a Windows user so not very good with ubuntu. Still I think this may help `"java -cp MY_PATH User | echo Sundeep"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Process.getOutputStream()` method. Any data passed to this output stream will be passed to the standard input stream read by your `User.java` main method.

Do not forget to write a `\n` character for the `br.readLine();` to detect end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and write your input data there.

```
OutputStream out = proc2.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
writer.write("World");
writer.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry, you code right. And we should also write new line after writing each input. `writer.newLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

Thought the above answers are write, I would like to produce the code for coming users :) The below method will accept all set of inputs(if we read more than one input for other programs) and writes them to bufferedWriter.

```
public static void giveInputToProcess(Process process, String[] inputs) {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            process.getOutputStream()));
    for (String input : inputs) {
        try {
            bw.write(input);
            bw.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```